# map is not function in object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I tried to link pass object and it say's map is  not a function. i tried all the way's but no luck. Any idea what mistake i made.

**input**

```
const sample = [
  {
    path: "/website",
    par: {
      abc: "234",
      def: "567",
      ghi: "8910"
    }
  }
];


{sample.length !== 0 ? (
        sample.map((sample) => (
          <Menu.Item
        
          >
            <Link
              to={{
                pathname: sample.path,
                search: createURL(sample)
              }}
            >
              {"Sample"}{" "}
            </Link>
          </Menu.Item>
```

[Map is not a function error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdnSN.png)

Comment: Is it really an array, or a string? what does `console.log(Array.isArray(sample))` output? Do you need to parse the string to an array with `JSON.parse?`

Comment: Try changing the object name to something else instead of same as your array name in map function sample.map((here) => {})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way also. You can check your data array using the `Optional chaining?`

For more about [Optional chaining?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Also, you need to verify your data is Array format or not. You can use `Array.isArray(sample)` for check that.

```
import React from "react";

const samples = [
  {
    path: "/website",
    par: {
      abc: "234",
      def: "567",
      ghi: "8910"
    }
  }
];

const App = () => {
  
  return (
   <React.Fragment>
    {Array.isArray(samples) && samples?.map(sample => {
      return (
        <div>
          {JSON.stringify(sample)}
        </div>
      )
    })}
  </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
{sample && sample.length && (
        <>
          {sample.map((item, index) => (
            <Menu.Item
              key={index}
              className={"text"}
            >
              <Link
                to={{
                  pathname: item.path,
                  search: createURL(item),
                }}
              >
                {"item"}{" "}
              </Link>
            </Menu.Item>
          ))}
        </>
      )}
```

Comment: If `sample` is a defined and empty array, then `.map` is certainly capable of handling that. This code may unintentionally output other values, like `0` if it is an empty array.